# Get the average

Tags: sql, postgresql, lambda

Can you make a query that

My data looks like this:

```
acccount_id | value | timestamp 
-------------------------------
a12         | 122   | jan 1
a13         | 133   | jan 1
a14         | 443   | jan 1
a12         | 251   | jan 2
a13         | 122   | jan 2
a14         | 331   | jan 2
a12         | 412   | jan 3
a13         | 323   | jan 3
a14         | 432   | jan 3
```

I would like to get the average for all previous days for each account.

```
acccount_id | value | timestamp | Average
-----------------------------------------
a12         |  122  | jan 1     | 122
a13         |  133  | jan 1     | 133
a14         |  443  | jan 1     | 443
a12         |  251  | jan 2     | 188.5
a13         |  122  | jan 2     | 222.5
a14         |  331  | jan 2     | 387
a12         |  412  | jan 3     | 261.6
a13         |  323  | jan 3     | 192.6
a14         |  432  | jan 3     | 402
```

I am not a pro with Postgres but I was looking into [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and it seems like the way to go but i couldn't get it to work correctly. I am obviously open to better options as well.

For more background, I will actually be generating new values every day and have a lambda function that is computing them. So a statement that will append where values do not exist would be exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You want a running average, and indeed this is done using window functions. When you supply an `ORDER BY` to the partition definition of the aggregate you get the running average

```
select account_id, value, "timestamp", 
       avg(value) over (partition by account_id order by "timestamp") as average
from the_table
order by account_id, "timestamp";
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. It seems to be working. Do you by any chance know how i would save that column?

Would i have to do something like this?

(pseudocode)

```
BEGIN;

select account_id, value, "timestamp", 
       avg(value) over (partition by account_id order by "timestamp") as average
into temp
from the_table
order by account_id, "timestamp";

ALTER TABLE table_a RENAME TO table_old;

ALTER TABLE temp RENAME TO table_a;

DROP table_old

COMMIT;
```